# Packer hangs waiting for (inline) Shell script to be executed

Tags: packer

being new to packer i am trying to build my first virtual box image with a packer file. But somehow it hangs on the inline shell provisioning. I cannot figure out what the issue is. Tried to debug and it hangs on.

> virtualbox-iso: Provisioning with shell script: /var/folders/27/p5wvd4l164z3c56378y7pp940000gn/T/packer-shell450560231

My packer script is as follows:

```
{
  "provisioners": [{
    "type": "shell",
    "inline": [
      "sleep 30",
      "sudo apt-get update"
    ]
  }],
  "builders": [
    {
      "type": "virtualbox-iso",
      "boot_command": [
        "<esc><wait>",
        "<esc><wait>",
        "<enter><wait>",
        "/install/vmlinuz<wait>",
        " auto<wait>",
        " console-setup/ask_detect=false<wait>",
        " console-setup/layoutcode=us<wait>",
        " console-setup/modelcode=pc105<wait>",
        " debian-installer=en_US<wait>",
        " fb=false<wait>",
        " initrd=/install/initrd.gz<wait>",
        " kbd-chooser/method=us<wait>",
        " keyboard-configuration/layout=USA<wait>",
        " keyboard-configuration/variant=USA<wait>",
        " locale=en_US<wait>",
        " netcfg/get_hostname=ubuntu-1404<wait>",
        " netcfg/get_domain=acme.com<wait>",
        " noapic<wait>",
        " preseed/url=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/preseed.cfg<wait>",
        " -- <wait>",
        "<enter><wait>"
      ],
      "boot_wait": "10s",
      "disk_size": 40960,
      "guest_os_type": "Ubuntu_64",
      "http_directory": "http",
      "iso_checksum": "9e5fecc94b3925bededed0fdca1bd417",
      "iso_checksum_type": "md5",
      "iso_url": "http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04.3-server-amd64.iso",
      "ssh_username": "packer",
      "ssh_password": "packer",
      "ssh_port": 22,
      "ssh_pty" : "true",
      "headless": "false",
      "ssh_wait_timeout": "10000s",
      "shutdown_command": "echo packer | sudo -S shutdown -P now",
      "output_directory": "/Users/marco/Desktop/generated_images/ubuntu",
      "vboxmanage": [
        [ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--memory", "512" ],
        [ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--cpus", "1" ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get verbose output from Packer with `PACKER_LOG=1` before the build command. That might help diagnose what's happening on particular scripts. Also packer has a --debug flag that will stop the build at breakpoints and enable you to login to the image.